# How to clean an input html in grails/groovy for ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, ckeditor, fckeditor

In my grails application, i use the ckeditor. I can save the content easily but when I edit the content, I can't fill the ckeditor. I receive a "unterminated string literal" due to this :

```
WRITTED CODE : var data = "${item.content}"
GENERATED CODE : var data = "<p> 
                  blavbl </p>"
```

I understand that's because the valu retruned by grails is multi line but how to manage this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please explain where is the generated code coming from? If you want a multi-line string literals you need to use triple quotes.

Comment: It's generated from database.

Comment: @Jonathan: just a comment: "I can save the content easily but when I edit the content, I can't fill the ckeditor". I think if you have time, you should re-check this problem. I use ckeditor too, but I don't have any trouble about saving "/r/n" into database.

Comment: @Hoang when I save, I don't have a problem on save but when I read the content, I use the method setData of ckeditor. And javascript don't accept the content with \r\n

Comment: @Jonathan: I don't use the method setData... I put the ckeditor code in the view, and get its content from database to a variable.

Comment: @Hoang: I tried with `<textarea name="myfield" id="myfield" value="${myobject.variable}" width="100%"></textarea>` but it's not working. I must use the method setData.

Comment: @Jonathan: sorry, my fault. I forget that what I use is not CKEditor, but the plugin CKEditor for Grails. I pushed this conservation a little too far... I think you can try out that plugin, it saves lots of works for me.

Comment: @Hoang thans a lot for your help. Perhaps I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with grails :

I use the replaceAll groovy method to replace \r\n with nothing and it's working.
I add this methods on domain object (setter and getter) and on the gsp.